# Embed html in Jupyter with R kernel

Tags: html, r, rcharts, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to display some html plots I have created with rCharts package.
It seems I've created'em well cause I can display these in Chrome.

The problem comes when I am coding in Jupyter notebook. I usually display htmls with IRdisplay package, and by doing this:

```
library(IRdisplay)
library(rCharts)
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ V2, group = "V1", data = x, type = "multiBarChart")
n1$save("NAME.html", standalone = TRUE)
display_html(file =  "NAME.html")
```

By just printing n1 or name.html I can display it, not in the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Even though this question was marked as duplicate, the solution I found wasn't the same than the one I'd already checked.
What I did in order to use it was:
`display_html('<iframe src="NAME.html" align="center" width="900" height="450" frameBorder="0"></iframe>')`
I hope if there is anyone with the same problem I had, they can try this.

Comment: There is support to "isolate" a full html page in an iframe, but this is currently only implemented in the kernel (= not in `display_html`) -> I opended https://github.com/IRkernel/IRdisplay/issues/19 . I the next version of repr/irkernel, `htmlwidgets` are also supported, but you need to have an `htmlwidget` object, not an rChart one, so `as.htmlwidget(n1)` might be needed.